# Integrate over a disk

Tags: integration, differential-forms, line-integrals

In a proove that I have to do in DoCarmo Differential Forms and aplications, There is a step that I can't understand.

If $D$ is a disk, $u(x,y);v(x,y)$ then:

$$\int_{\partial D} \frac{u du+vdv}{u^2+v^2} = 0 $$

Another way to see (That the book give as a hint) is to see that is the same as:
$$ \int_{\partial D} d(\log(u^2+v^2)) = 0 $$

Is clear the reason that is the same but I don't know why is 0.

If I have that, I can prove what I need, but I don't know how to argue why that integral is 0.

Please help with this.

Comment: Better proof: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on $\partial D$ and don't even think about $D$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $D$ is a disk where $u^2+v^2$ does not vanish, then this is a consequence of Stokes' theorem.

Stokes' thoerem says for any domain $D$ with boundary $\partial D$, the exact differential $d\omega$ has integral given by

$$
\int_Dd\omega=\int_{\partial D}\omega.
$$

In your case, we have that 
$$d(\log(u^2+v^2))=\frac{\partial (\log z)}{\partial z}\,dz=\frac{\partial \log z}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}dv\right)\Big|_{z=u^2+v^2}\\
=\frac{1}{u^2+v^2}\left(2u\,du+2v\,dv\right)=2\frac{u\,du+v\,dv}{u^2+v^2}.
$$

Which up to a factor of $2$ is the integrand you started with.

So that becomes

$$
\int_D\frac{u\,du+v\,dv}{u^2+v^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial D}d(\log(u^2+v^2))=\frac{1}{2}\int_Dd^2(\log(u^2+v^2)).
$$

The exterior derivative satisfies $d^2=0$, which is ultimately a consequence of the equality of mixed partial derivatives on $C^2$ functions, so $d^2(\log(u^2+v^2))=0,$ and so we have $\int_{\partial D}d(\log(u^2+v^2))=0.$

Note that this fails on any domain $D$ which includes $u=v=0.$